# Failed connection to Laravel app through Insomnia for testing

Tags: php, laravel, insomnia

I am new on Laravel (I am using the 8.17.2 version)

I am still learning and I tried using the method "GET" through Insomnia to get the list of users

And it gives me this on the timeline:

```
* Preparing request to http://appdeefe.dev/users
* Current time is 2021-01-11T03:37:17.770Z
* Using libcurl/7.69.1-DEV OpenSSL/1.1.1d zlib/1.2.11 WinIDN libssh2/1.9.0_DEV nghttp2/1.40.0
* Using default HTTP version
* Disable timeout
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 0 cookies
* Hostname appdeefe.dev was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.168.10.11:80...
* connect to 192.168.10.11 port 80 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to appdeefe.dev port 80: Timed out
* Closing connection 5
```

Do you know how can I solve this?

Note: I also have the same problem using Postman, so most likely the problem is not related to Insomnia.

Comment: Did you add this entry to your local hosts file? `appdeefe.dev`

Comment: are you able to run your laravel app on browser ?

Comment: @bassxzero no, i can't connect to my local hosts file neither.

Comment: @KamleshPaul no. I run on the console "php artisan serve" and then it tells me that the development server is started on 127.0.0.1:8000 but when i tried to access that direction through the browser it gives me "404 Not found".

Comment: @Deefe yeah it means your laravel application have some issue

Comment: @bassxzero sorry, i didn't read your question well. I don't remember adding that entry 'appdeefe.dev'. How do I do that?